# Calculating the difference between consecutive rows by group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of ids and timestamps. I'd like to calculate the difference between each sequential timestamp for an individual id.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
id  time
Alpha   1
Alpha   4
Alpha   7
Beta    5
Beta    10
```

I'm trying to add a column like `time.difference` below:

```
id  time    time.difference
Alpha   1   NA
Alpha   4   3
Alpha   7   4
Beta    5   NA
Beta    10  5
```

Is there a clean way to do this using dplyr? (or tidyr or something else that's easier to read than vanilla R?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like this:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time.difference = time - lag(time))
```

Comment: One thing to add to this answer (after a long wait).  This works because the data is already sorted by id and time in the example.  If it wasn't sorted, `lag` would not work reliably.  A more robust solution would add `arrange(time) %>%` between the `group_by' and the `mutate` functions.  That would ensure that the data is sorted properly for the `lag` function

Comment: It does not seem to work either if you group by several columns.

Comment: @hank_044 I believe you need to arrange by id, not time.  At least then it works for me. It should read `arrange(id) %>%`

Answer (score 7):

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
setDT(dat)[, time.difference := time - lag(time, 1L), by = id]
```