# dplyr not grouping correctly or else using data from previous groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with [JHU data on coronavirus infections](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19), and I'm trying to compute new cases (and deaths) by group. Here's the code:

```
base <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-"
world.confirmed <- read.csv(paste0(base,"Confirmed.csv"), sep=',', head=T)
world.confirmed <- gather( world.confirmed, Date, Cases, X1.22.20:X3.21.20)

world.deaths <- read.csv(paste0(base,"Deaths.csv"), sep=',', head=T)
world.deaths <- gather(world.deaths, Date, Deaths, X1.22.20:X3.21.20)

world.data <- merge(world.confirmed, world.deaths, 
                 by=c("Province.State","Country.Region","Lat", "Long", "Date"))

world.data$Date <- as.Date(world.data$Date, "X%m.%d.%y")
world.data <- world.data %>% 
    group_by(Province.State,Country.Region,Date) %>%
    arrange(Province.State, Country.Region, as.Date(Date))
```

Following [solutions to this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049092/difference-between-rows-in-r-on-dataframe-grouped-by-column) I have tried to compute differences by group using something like this:

```
world.data <- world.data %>% 
   group_by(Lat,Long) %>% 
   mutate(New.Cases = Cases - lag(Cases))
```

That does not work, however; any other grouping does not either. Here're results on boundary between two first countries:

[image: Value for first element of Albania]

I have tried also inserting an `arrange` phase, and even trying to zero the first element of the group. Same problem. Any idea?

*Update* I'm using R 3.4.4 and dplyr_0.8.5

Comment: Hey when I ran your code, line 61 with Albania gives me NA.. so did something get funky in your R session, I am on R.3.6.1,  tidyr_1.0.0 dplyr_0.8.3

Comment: @StupidWolf maybe it's time to upgrade R. Let me check.

Comment: @StupidWolf fixed after upgrading to 3.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this might help :

```
library(dplyr)

world.data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "X%m.%d.%y")) %>% 
  arrange(Country.Region, Lat, Long, Date) %>%
  group_by(Country.Region, Lat, Long) %>%
  mutate(New_Cases = Cases - lag(Cases), 
         New_deaths = Deaths - lag(Deaths))
```

We `arrange` the data according to `Date`, and find `New_Cases` by subtracting today's case with yesterday's case for each `Country` and the same for deaths.

Comment: Not really. Dates were already formatted. The only difference I see is that you're grouping and arranging using more columns; anyway, that does not work either (and I don't really see why it should, except you're sorting by date, but as in the example, sorting was already taken care of)

Comment: @jjmerelo  It would be good to know what do you mean by "working". Can you show what your expected output would look like? If it's difficult to share it for original data please create a small reproducible example and show output for that example.

Comment: I got the same result as above. The problem, as indicated in the comment, was the R version.